# How to tell excel to copy from one sheet to another with the condition?

Tags: excel, if-statement, filter, spreadsheet

I have an excel sheet which has around 4000 rows.
Its about treatment details about the patients, where there are patients repeatedly came for the tests.

Now, wanted to create   a new sheet which allows me to collect info from the old sheet.

conditions:

1. I need only one row represent a patient.
2. The second column onwards the info has be filled in the following way.

for example, if the data is entered in the following way:

```
 patient_id   test1   test2     test3
 001            1        0          1
 001            0        1          0
 .
 .
 .
 002            1         1          1
 002            0         0          0
 .
 .
 .
 003            1         0          0
 .
 .
 .
```

Now the in the new sheet, the first column should show the patient id and in the second column if she has alteast one 1 in her follow up(means if she has 1 in any of her visit in the test1) it should return 1 otherwise 0.

I dont know how many times a patient come for test.. its not uniform.

Similarly for the second and third column.

How to do that??

I hope patient name column also can be entered in the sameway.

If its not possible and can be done easily in other softwares..I wish to know that.

Thanks for helping!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a pivot table you can filter on patient ID and test.

From this dataset

[image]

you will get something like this

[image]

To insert a pivot table go to the Insert tab and select pivot table

[image]

and then apply the following settings

[image]

In the filter on patient ID then simply select the patient ID you want to see.
More extensive tutorials on how to use and set pivot tables can be found on the internet, like [this one](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: infact i dont want the sum...rather i wanted to present the value 1 if for any of the follow up days he had 1.

Comment: I don't get what you are looking for. Can you make an example?

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply..  I meant to say I want the max in the place of sums...I got that..